# How can I calculate the residue at a point of degree n?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to understand this solution in the book but I am not very good at math:

> Problem: We want to fins the degree of the pole at $z= \frac{1}{2}$
> and its residue $$ f(z) = \frac{1-e^{2z-1}}{(z-\frac{1}{2})^2} $$

---

Solution:
After substitution with t=2z-1 we get this but I don't understand what formulas are used to get the residue of -4/3. I see that first step is to expand $e^t$ using Taylor to see where the division is 1 and where the numerator is 0 och denumerator is 0 at the same time so we can remove common singularities, right? But what happens after that?

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of a pole and residue?

Comment: The residue at $\frac1  2$ is the coefficient of $\frac 1 {z-\frac 1 2 }$ in the Laurent series expansion.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational, pole is where the division is undefined. From what I understand Residue is a value to an integral wich would otherwise be undefined of a pole that is located inside a closed contour which is integrated in a clockwise fashion.

Comment: No I mean the exact definition, that what you said is more like an intuition than definition. Check wikipedia for instance.

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational, which formula? Multiple pole formula?

Comment: @geetha290krm, so basically Laurent series is Taylor series variant I see, Wiki tells me its a_(-1) coeffiecient of that series. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For a pole of order n the formula for calculating the residue of some complex function is;

$$\mathrm{Res}_m(f(z))={1\over(n-1)!}\cdot \lim_{z\rightarrow m}{{d^{n-1}}\over{dz^{n-1}}}((z-m)^nf(z))$$

So for your specific function we have a pole of order 2 at $z={1\over2}$;

$$\mathrm{Res}_{1\over2}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow m}{d\over dz}(1-e^{2z-1})=(-2\cdot e^{0})=-2$$

$$\therefore \mathrm{Res}_{1\over2}f(z)= -2$$

Comment: You can get nice limit formatting just by using `\lim`. If you simply type `lim`, mathjax thinks it is three variables $l, i, m$ multiplied together.  "Res" is a little harder, as it doesn't have a defined name like lim does. But you can use `\mathrm{Res}` or just `\text{Res}`.